# HTML - Stop Auto-playing of video

Tags: html, iframe, html5-video

I've a video embedded in my HTML, and it autoplays on reload. I want to disable the autoplay feature. I've tried `autoplay = "false"` property , but it doesnt work.

Here's my code

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   <iframe src="https://d1a2y8pfnfh44t.cloudfront.net/b79fac80851111e3b3e3a539a6199a02/full/540p/index.mp4" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
   </iframe>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your tags are confusing because you are not using the video tag for  HTML5. Can you use HTML5?

Comment: Why is it confusing???

Comment: Because your "post tag" `html5-video` implies that you are using the  `<video></video>` element

Comment: Oh Ok. So, how can i disable autoplay in iframe?

Comment: WhaT video player is that ?

Comment: I dont know!!! This is one of the video from the coursera videos!!!